# How do I integrate an 'async function()' into the Protractor control flow?

Tags: protractor

I have a Protractor test suite that has been partially converted to use `async` / `await` instead of the control flow, but I need to call some `async` helper functions from old-style tests that still need the control flow. How can I make sure the `async` `Promise` executes in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async functions return a `Promise`. Use `browser.controlFlow().wait(Promise)` to explicitly add these to the control flow.

```
 it('is a test', function () {
   let flow = browser.controlFlow();
   ordinaryHelper();
   flow.wait(asyncHelper());
 });
```